# I cant getSupportFragment in the Home Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

i create a home fragment and inside i create tab layout and using a java class and extend of `fragmentPagerAdapter` then when i want to initialize the TabAdapter in home fragment need `getSupportFragmentManager` and i cant set that in a fragment (home fragment) what can i do for fix it ?

my TabAdapter codes :

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private int numberOfTabs;

public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
    super(fm);
    this.numberOfTabs = behavior;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new MobileCatFragment();

        case 1:
            return new TabletCatFragment();

        case 2:
            return new LaptopCatFragment();

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numberOfTabs;
}
}
```

and my home fragment when i try to intialize the TabAdapter :

```
TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter( ???  , tlCategory.getTabCount());
```

tlCategory is my TabLayout...

Update:

its my home fragment codes :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    sessionManager = new SessionManager(getContext());
    TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()  , tlCategory.getTabCount());

    imgBtnSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSearch);
    imgBtnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchDialog();
        }
    });

    svBanner = view.findViewById(R.id.svBanner);
    svBanner.setAutoCycle(true);
    svBanner.setScrollTimeInSec(8);
    svBanner.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM);
    showBanner();

    tlCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.tlCategory);
    tiMobile = view.findViewById(R.id.tiMobile);
    tiTablet = view.findViewById(R.id.tiTablet);
    tiLaptop = view.findViewById(R.id.tiLaptop);
    vpTabs = vpTabs.findViewById(R.id.vpTabs);
    vpTabs.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
    tlCategory.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            vpTabs.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling TabAdapter from fragment please use `TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter( getChildFragmentManager(), tlCategory.getTabCount());`

and is you are calling TabAdapter from AppCompatActivity/Activity use
`TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager(), tlCategory.getTabCount());`

Comment: @mohammadmansouri please upload homefragment code

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0):

It's should be ChildFragmentManager because you can't call getSupportFragmentManger() with Fragment reference

```
TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter( getChildFragmentManager()  , tlCategory.getTabCount());
```

or you have call with activity reference

```
requirActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```